# Output all numbers below certain number containing certain digits

Tags: code-golf, number

## Output all numbers in certain range containing certain digits

#### Task

1. Take an input of digits through console, prompt, or a file (in the decimal number system). These digits should be separated by spaces.
2. Take an input of the "maximum" through console, prompt, or a file
3. If you use a file, the program must output `"[Data taken from file]"`
4. Print all [natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) (including 0) below the maximum containing **at least one** of the digits specified by the user (they may contain other digits), separated by a single space. **Leading `0`s do not count!**
5. If there is a sequence of 10 or more consecutive numbers, it should output the first and last, separated by a `-->`

#### Rules

- Standard loopholes are (obviously) not allowed
- Programs must complete the tasks above
- The answer with the fewest characters wins

#### Examples

```
>>> 1 3
>>> 100
1 3 10 --> 19 21 23 30 --> 39 41 43 51 53 61 63 71 73 81 83 91 93
```

---

```
>>> 1 2 4 5 6 7
>>> 29
1 2 4 5 6 7 10 --> 28
```

---

```
>>> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>>> 9999999
0 --> 9999998
```

---

```
[Data taken from file]
1 3 5 7 9
```

Comment: Please be specific about the format for digits input: space separated (as in examples), comma separated, a single string (136) or whatever.

Comment: Does the arrow have to be `->` or would a Unicode arrow like `→` also be fine?

Comment: @MartinBüttner It has to be `-->`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### GolfScript <s>74</s> 71 ([DEMO](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OycxIDMgMTAwJwoKJyAnOsKnLyl%2BXG4qOng7LHtgeCZ9LDk5OmM7ey5jKT0he8KnXH0qOmN9JVvCp10vey4sOT57KCctLT4nQClcO317fn1pZn0lwqcq&run=true))

```
' ':§/)~\n*:x;,{`x&},99:c;{.c)=!{§\}*:c}%[§]/{.,9>{('-->'@)\;}{~}if}%§*
```

#### Description:

The code expects the parameters passed via the console, like so:

```
echo "1 3 100" | ruby golfscript.rb numbers.gs
```

Here's the annotated code:

```
' ':§/                  # Split input by space and save the 
                        # space character in variable `§`

)~                      # Take the last input and convert to int
                        # This is the "maximum" parameter.

\n*:x;                  # Take the list of digits and join them with 
                        # newlines, resulting in a string.
                        # Save the result in variable `x` and take it
                        # off the stack

,                       # Take the "maximum" parameter and make an 
                        # array [0, max)

{`x&},                  # Filter the array, leaving only numbers that
                        # contain the right digits (that have at least
                        # one char in common with string `x`)

99:c;                   # Save the value 99 in a new variable, `c`.

{                       # For each element (`n`) in the array:
  .                     #   - duplicate `n` on the stack
  c)=!{§\}*             #   - if it does not equal `c`+1 add a space before it
  :c                    #   - assign the value of `n` to `c`
}%

[§]/                    # Split the resulting array by spaces

{                       # For each element `a` in the array of arrays:
  .                     #   - duplicate `a` on the stack
  ,9>                   #   - check if length > 9
  {('-->'@)\;}          #   - if `a`'s length is >9, then push "(min)", "-->" and "(max)"
                        #     on the stack
  {~}if                 #   - otherwise, just place the elements of the current array 
                        #     on the stack
}%
§*                      # make a string representing the elements of the resulting array,
                        # separated by spaces
```

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, <del>186</del> <del>181</del> 177 bytes

```
a=gets.split;puts ([0]+(0...gets.to_i).select{|x|(x.to_s.split('')&a).any?}).each_cons(2).slice_before{|m,n|m+1<n}.map{|a|c=a.map &:last;c.count>9?[c[0],'-->',c.last]:c}.join' '
```

Ungolfed explanation:

```
# Read numbers from input and split into array
a = gets.split

# Loop from 0 to maximum number, exclusive
puts ([0]+(0...gets.to_i).select { |x| 
  # Only include numbers that include at least one input digit
  (x.to_s.split('')&a).any?
})    # Add dummy element to the beginning of array
.each_cons(2)   # Get each array of 2 consecutive elements
.slice_before { |m, n| #
  m + 1 < n # "Slice" the array if m and n are not consecutive
}.map { |a|
  c = a.map &:last # Get all the last elements in `a`
  if c.count > 9
    # 10 or more consecutive elements. Get the first and last, and
    # an arrow in-between
    [c[0],'-->',c.last]
  else
    c
  end
}.join ' ' # Add space in-between all elements, and print result
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (E6) 153 <s>157 161 163 177</s>

Input and output via `prompt`

The main loop filters the numbers with a regexp and builds spans of consecutive numbers (as arrays). The O function concatenates the spans converting them to string. If the elements in a span array are 10 or more, instead of taking all elelements it just take the first and last number.

Test in FireFox/FireBug console

```javascript
P=prompt,m=P(d=P());
O=_=>(
  o+=s[9]?s[0]+" -->"+p:s.join(''),s=[]
);
for(s=[o=''],p=n=0;n<m;++n)
  (n+'').match("["+d+"]")&&
  (
    n+~p&&O(),s.push(p=' '+n)
  );
O(),P(o)
```

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <s>233</s> <s>191</s> <s>171</s> 165 bytes

```
t=StringSplit;Flatten[Split[Cases[Range@Input[d=t@InputString[]]-1,m_/;ToString@m~t~""⋂d!={}],#2-#<2&]/.{e:{__Integer}/;Length@e>9:>{#&@@e,"-->",Last@e}}]~Row~"  "
```

I'm taking the input from two prompts which is as close to command line as it gets in Mathematica.

Ungolfed:

```
t = StringSplit;
Flatten[
  Split[
    Cases[
     Range@Input[d = t@InputString[]] - 1,
     m_ /; ToString@m~t~"" \[Intersection] d != {}
     ],
    #2 - # < 2 &
    ] /. {e : {__Integer} /; Length@e > 9 :> {# & @@ e, "-->", Last@e}}
  ]~Row~"  "
```

I'm simply filtering a range with all numbers to the relevant ones and then I'm collapsing consecutive subsequences with a repeated rule replacement.

Comment: Shorter, using `String` to aid finding runs: `t = StringSplit;
Row[Flatten[
  Split[ (Cases[Range[Input[d = t@InputString[]] - 1], 
      m_ /; ToString@m~t~"" \[Intersection] d != {}]), #2 - # == 1 &] /. {e : {a__Integer} /; 
      Length[{a}] > 9 :> {e[[1]] -> e[[-1]]}}], "   "]`

Comment: @DavidCarraher Nice! Thanks a lot. I don't think the `->` shortcut is fair game though. I'll ask the OP.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Range[0, Input[d = t@InputString[]] - 1]` instead of `Range[Input[d = t@InputString[]] - 1]`?

Comment: @DavidCarraher Oh, I didn't see that `0` was included. But in that case decrementing the default range by `1` is shorter.

Comment: Yes, it's shorter, but it only tests through max-1, not max.

Comment: @David so does yours and that's the required behaviour

Comment: Hmm, the -1 can be removed from mine.  It will then behave properly!

Comment: @DavidCarraher But the upper end *should* be excluded from the range, as per the challenge spec.

Comment: You are correct! I hadn't noticed that in the specs.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl - <s>170</s> 162

```
$a=<>;chop$a;$a=~s/ /|/g;@b=grep{/$a/}(0..<>-1);while(++$c<@b){if($b[$c]-$b[$c-1]>1){($e=$c-$d)>9&&splice(@b,$d+1,$e-2,'-->')&&($c-=$e-3);$d=$c}}print join' ',@b
```

Ungolfed with comments:

```
$a=<>;    #Read digits
chop$a;$a=~s/ /|/g;    #Turn digit string into regex
@b=grep{/$a/}(0..<>-1);    #Assign @b as list of numbers from 0 to second input which match the digits
while(++$c<@b){    #Loop $c through indexes of list
    if($b[$c]-$b[$c-1]>1){    #If next number is not consecutive, do arrow adding stuff
        ($e=$c-$d)>9&&    #If the number of previous consecutive numbers is at least 10
            splice(@b,$d+1,$e-2,'-->')&&    #Replace all but the first and last with '-->'
            ($c-=$e-3);    #Subtract from index to compensate for decreased list length
        $d=$c    #Set $d (fist index of consecutive range) to current index
    }
}
print join' ',@b    #Print the list
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 105 (or 110 if you need to add `.chop` to the gets to make your input work)

Run with command line flags `pl`.

```
r=/[#$_]/
$_=(?1...gets).grep(r).slice_before{|e|-1>eval("#@l-"+@l=e)}.map{|a|a[9]?[a[0],'-->',a[-1]]:a}*' '
```

Convert the first input to a character class in a regex. Generate all numeric strings between 1 and the next input (exclusive) and find the ones that match the regex. `slice_before` trick is stolen from August to find contiguous ranges, it gets shorter by using an instance variable to remember the last element so I don't need `each_cons`, but longer since I'm working with strings. I check for ranges of size 10 or more by seeing whether they have a 10th element or not (`a[9]`), and replace their internal elements with the arrow.

Answer (score 2):

## Python - <s>208 202</s> 211

```
D=raw_input()
n=input()
s=[`i`for i in range(n)if sum(d in`i`for d in D)]
i=0
while i<len(s):
 j=len(s)
 while j:
  j-=1
  try:
   if int(s[j])-int(s[i])==j-i>8:s[i+1:j]=['-->']
  except:1
 i+=1
print' '.join(s)
```

Comment: Doesn't this produce a wrong output formating? For me (Python 2.7) it outputs something like ['1', '2', '3'].

Comment: @Emil: Sorry, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash+coreutils, 94 bytes

```
seq -s\  0 $[$1-1]|sed -r "s/\b[^ ${2// }]+\b/:/g
s/([0-9]+)( [0-9]+){9,}/\1 -->\2/g
s/: ?//g"
```

- `seq` generates all numbers below the maximum
- The first `sed` line replaces any number not containing the interesting digits with `:`
- The second `sed` line searches for runs of 10 or more space-separated numbers and replaces with `start --> end`
- The final `sed` line removes unnecessary `:` and spaces.

#### Output:

```
$ ./belowdigits.sh 100 "1 3"
1 3 10 --> 19 21 23 30 --> 39 41 43 51 53 61 63 71 73 81 83 91 93 
$ ./belowdigits.sh 29 "1 2 4 5 6 7"
1 2 4 5 6 7 10 --> 28
$ ./belowdigits.sh 999999 "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
0 --> 999998
$
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 227

Currently the longest, but whatever.

```py
a=raw_input().split()
l=[i for i in range(input())if any(x in str(i)for x in a)]
for i in l:
 for j in l[::-1]:
  try:L=l.index;l=l[:L(i)+1]+['-->']+l[L(j):]if j-i==L(j)-L(i)and j-i>8 else l
  except:1
print' '.join(map(str,l))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>195</s> 194

```
main=interact$(\[d,m]->v$f(any(`elem`f(/=' ')d).s)[0..read m-1]).lines
s=show
f=filter
v l@(x:m)|g l>x+8=unwords[s x,"->",s$g l,v$f(>g l)l]|0<1=s x++' ':v m
v[]=""
g s=f(`notElem`s)[s!!0..]!!0-1
```

not very short but Imho quite good for this specific question and language.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <strike>202</strike> 191

Another try at Python, using the same idea as @August's Ruby solution:

```python
a=raw_input()
s=[x for x in range(input())if any(c in`x`for c in a)]
for _,g in __import__('itertools').groupby(s,lambda x:x+1in s):
 l=map(str,g)
 print len(l)<9and' '.join(l)or l[0]+' -->',
```

PS: Coincidentally, the first two lines ended up nearly identical to both other Python entries.

Answer (score 1):

## R 224 w/o Comment

```
a=as.character
l=length
x=a(scan())                                                 # Read digits
s=a(0:(scan()-1))                                           # Read max number
p=as.numeric(s[Reduce(`|`,lapply(x,function(x)grepl(x,s)))])# Find all numbers we want
j=1                                                         # Print the arrow "-->"
for (i in 1:l(z<-c(rle(diff(p))$l,1))){if(z[i]<9)cat(p[j:(j+z[i]-1)],"")else
cat(p[j],"-->","")
j=j+z[i]}
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, <s>273</s> <s>258</s> <s>255</s> <s>248</s> <s>256</s> <s>239</s> 234 bytes

What a mess.

#### Submission:

```
function n($s,$b){$r=$q=$f="";for($g=-1;$g++<$b;){$i=0;foreach(explode(" ",$s)as$d){$i+=in_array($d,str_split($g));}if($i&&$b-$g){$q[]=$g;$f=$f?:$g;}elseif($f){$r.=($g-$f>9?$q[0]." --> ".($g-1):implode(" ",$q))." ";$q=$f="";}}echo$r;}
```

#### Exploded view:

```
function n($s, $b) {
  $r = $q = $f = "";
  for ($g = -1; $g++ < $b;) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach(explode(" ", $s) as $d) {
      $i += in_array($d, str_split($g));
    }
    if ($i && $b-$g) { 
      $q[] = $g;
      $f = $f ?: $g;
    } elseif ($f){ 
      $r .= ($g-$f > 9 ? $q[0] . " --> " . ($g-1)
                       : implode(" ", $q)        ) . " ";
      $q = $f = "";
    }
  }
  echo $r;
}
```

#### Variable explanations:

`$b`: *string*, upper **b**ound (input)
`$s`: *string*, digit **s**tring (input)
`$d`: *int*, individual **d**igit in `$s`
`$g`: *int*, current **g**uess
`$i`: *int*, number of times a digit exists **i**n the current guess
`$f`: *int*, **f**irst correct guess in a chain
`$q`: *array*, correct guess **q**ueue
`$r`: *string*, final **r**esult (output)

This is **super** unoptimized, still tweaking it.

**Edits:**
**-18:** Combining variable inits, merging two `$i` inits.
**-7:** Removing `$a` declaration.
**+8:** Fixed two bugs: now allows `0` as output, now allows `$b-1` and `--> $b-1` as output.
**-17:** God, I love ternary operators.
**-5:** Let's treat `$i` as an `int` full-time, and simplify the resets.